# RadioButton force close application

Tags: android, radio-button

I'am having a problem with my radiogroup, the app will force close if the user will not choose an answer, also, if the user will choose an answer, it will be the same answer on the second question. Also, how can I add a prompt message when user is not choosing any answer when pressing the next button? Your answer would be much appreciated. Thank you

Here is the java file

```
  public class QuizActivity extends Activity{
        List<Question> quesList;
        int score=0;
        int qid=0;
        Question currentQ;
        TextView txtQuestion;
        RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
        Button butNext;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
            DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
            quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
            currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
            txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
            rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
            butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            setQuestionView();
            butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                    RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
                    if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
                    {
                        score++;
                        Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
                    }
                    if(qid<5){
                        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                        setQuestionView();
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                        intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
            return true;
        }
        private void setQuestionView()
        {
            txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
            rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
            rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
            rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
            qid++;
        }
    }
```

Here is the xml file

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.04">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_next"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could add a `Toast` in the `next's` area respective logic.

Answer (score 0):

If the user don't choose anything you can control it like this:

```
if(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != null){
   //do something
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have to choose one option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

About the same answer in the next question, you have to reset before all the radio buttons. Something like this:

```
rda.setChecked(false);
rdb.setChecked(false);
rdc.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However the Line if(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != null) is under red line saying Operator != cannot be applied to int,null

Comment: Ah ok, so try this : if(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() > 0)

Comment: Also, The getActivity is under red line. saying cannot resolve method

Comment: Try this: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have to choose one option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: There are no red lines on the code now. But when I try to clean and rebuild the application. Im having an error saying Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0] C:\Users\Pc\NavigationDrawer2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-appindexing\8.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml
 Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.appindexing" to force usage

Comment: Already solved the android manifest error.. However, the solution provided b ARP is not working. Application is still force closing